# Convert an extent to rect

Tags: c#, .net, math

I need to convert an extents BottomLeft (-180, -90), TopRight (180, 90) to **System.Windows.Rect**. Rect is created using top left position and size of rect so, I tried to create it using position as (-180, 90) and size as width & height of above extents but which is wrong.

So, I am unable to create Rect for the above extents. Please help in creating it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rectangle can be represented as:

```
Rectangle d = new Rectangle(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, width, height);
```

where coordinates relevant here is that of the top-left corner. So you should calculate these parameters from the coordinates available to you. In your case:

```
Rectangle d = new Rectangle(-90, 180, 180, 360);
```

where

```
width = right - left
height = top - bottom
```